Host networking issue while inside docker accessing an exposed Kubernetes port
I am running a local cluster with an exposed port with port forwarding and all calls to it are working properly on the host itself.
However, when I attempt to connect to the same port from within a docker container, it fails. I've tried several networking configurations.
The network path would be something like: [Docker container] -> [Local machine] -> [Kubernetes port forwarding and NodePort] -> [Kubernetes Node] -> [Service].
The IP address "172.27.32.1" is the local machine running both Kubernetes and the docker container.
Commands
Test connectivity on the local machine to the service running in Kubernetes with the commands:
$ curl -m 3 localhost:8082
[All good]
$ curl -m 3 172.27.32.1:8082
[All good]

Run a docker container to simulate the network issues encountered during docker build --network host ... commands:
$ docker run --rm -it --network host curlimages/curl -m 3 172.27.32.1:8082
[Failed to connect ... couldn't connect to server]

$ docker run --rm -it --network host --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway curlimages/curl -m 3 host.docker.internal:8082
[Failed to connect ... couldn't connect to server]

$ docker run --rm -it --network host --add-host host.docker.internal:172.27.32.1 curlimages/curl -m 3 host.docker.internal:8082
[Failed to connect ... couldn't connect to server]

Specific technology in use

Windows 11 Pro
Rancher Desktop with docker (moby) engine
k3d for Kubernetes cluster automation *This is technically optional to the technology stack and could have easily used the Rancher Desktop default cluster. A local machine cluster simply has to exist on the machine.
Tilt for docker build and Kubernetes deployment automation *This is technically optional to the technology stack and is just a task automation abstraction.

Steps to reproduce

Cluster is created with k3d (instead of using the default Rancher Desktop cluster)

Docker images are built through Rancher Desktop's docker implementation via Tilt automation. The service container uses EXPOSE 8081 and the Kubernetes configuration uses a NodePort to map and expose the internal container port outside of the cluster.

Kubernetes deployment via Tilt automation including port forwarding to expose the port to the local machine.
# Ensure support for any IP using `0.0.0.0`.
# Depends on the context deployment for the service (e.g. namespace and ConfigMap)
k8s_resource('nexus-web', port_forwards='0.0.0.0:8082:8081', resource_deps=['nexus-web-context'])


At this point, calls to the local machine's localhost:8082 are responding as expected.

The docker run --network host ... command is used to reproduce an issue encountered with a docker build --network host ... command in Tilt automation after the Kubernetes port forwarding is completed. This includes a script to wait for endpoint responsiveness before proceeding so that we can availability is guaranteed.


Why docker run and not put the container in Kubernetes?
Running the docker container inside of Kubernetes is not possible, because this issue is actually a replication of a failing docker build --network host ... build step that attempts to access the service running from within the Kubernetes cluster. As a result, the entire docker build ... process would also have to run within Kubernetes and would result in new "docker in docker" challenges along with a sequencing issue. The docker run --network host ... is a simple reproduction of the underlying issue.
Alternative to NodePort
As an alternative to exposing the NodePort, another attempt was made to configure the exposed service in Kubernetes to explicitly use the host network with the same issues.
...
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet

A visual depiction


If it's a NodePort-type Service, can you connect directly to it without the port forward?  Can you replace the image with the text of the commands you're running?  kubectl port-forward normally binds to the localhost interface in a way that may not be reachable by host.docker.internal, but host networking should work (if it works at all; if you're using Docker on a native-Linux host without Docker Desktop).

Commands, technology stack and steps to reproduce have been added @DavidMaze. Thank you for the suggestion.

@DavidMaze, I noted that I used the "Alternative to NodePort" syntax in the k8s deployment. I could try commenting out both the NodePort implementation as well as the alternative spec.hostNetwork and spec.dnsPolicy alternative and see what happens with Kubernetes port forwarding.
